# Maximize $\frac{\sum_i \lambda_i x_i}{\sum_i |x_i|}$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Suppose $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ under the constraint that $Ax = 0$. $A$ is a $m(<n)$ by $n$ matrix whose first row is $(1,1,\ldots,1)$. We want to find an $x$ that maximizes $$\frac{\sum_i \lambda_i x_i}{\sum_i |x_i|}$$ for some $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n) \in ker(A)$ among all non-zero $x$.

My intuition is that we first write out a basis of $ker(A)$ as $\{\lambda,\alpha,\ldots,\beta\}$ and then we try adding $\{\alpha,\ldots,\beta\}$ to $\lambda$ so that $x=\lambda+c_1\alpha+c_2\beta+\cdots$ has the same order of elements as $\lambda$ and also majorizes $\lambda$. But I don't know if it is correct. Also I hope to find an analytical expression of $x$ as a function of the basis of $ker(A)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started solving this problem, but did not end up with a final answer. I'm still posting this so others may continue (or not make the same derivations to arrive at the same conclusion).

Note that if $x$ is optimal, then so is $cx$ for $c>0$. We can therefore rewrite the problem to:
$$\max_x \left\{ \sum_i \lambda_i x_i : \sum_i |x_i| \leq 1, Ax=0\right\}$$
Note that this is a convex optimization problem (and can be written as a linear optimization problem and solved by free solvers like Clp). Its Lagrangian is:
$$L(x,y,z) = \sum_i \lambda_i x_i - y\left(\sum_i |x_i| - 1\right) + \sum_i (A_i^Tz)x_i$$
The dual is obtained by taking the maximum over $x$. The maximum is $\infty$ unless $|\lambda_i + A_i^Tz| \leq y \; \forall i$. The dual is therefore:
$$\min_{y\geq 0,z} \left\{ y : |\lambda_i + A_i^Tz| \leq y \; \forall i \right\}$$
or:
$$\min_{z} \max_i |\lambda_i + A_i^Tz|$$
I don't see if there is an analytical solution to the dual. If there is, you can easily obtain a solution to the original problem.

Comment: I don't understand how to obtain the optimal $x$ if we know an analytical solution of the optimal value $\min_{z} \max_i |\lambda_i + A_i^Tz|$. Do you mind elaborating on the last sentence of your answer?

Comment: @Doris an optimal $x$ maximizes the Lagrangian (where $y$ and $z$ are fixed to their optimal values).

Comment: Thank you so much! To make sure I fully understand your point -- In general, in order to find an optimal $x$, we first identify the $x$'s which maximize the Lagrangian (with optimal $y$ and $z$) and then we solve the constraints to find the optimal $x$. Is that correct?

Comment: There is only one $x$ that is optimal to the Lagrangian, and it satisfies the constraints.

Comment: For example, in this question $x=0$ maximizes the Lagrangian, but it is not optimal?

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset together with the dual solution $z$?